# Routing through a 2nd network with a Procurve 2848

Tags: switch, hp-procurve

I've got an old Procurve 2848 sat in the office I'm trying to figure out and struggling with.

I'm trying to setup a route through to my other network & out to the internet.

I have a Cisco managed router providing DHCP services on my office network and I have another server that I've setup providing DHCP services on my "other" network.

I have configured the Procurve on 2 VLANs both of which use DHCP to get IP addresses from the DHCP servers. I have also setup a default gateway so that technically I should be able to route other stuff from my other network to the outside world.

From the other network, I can ping the Procurve switch on both IP address ranges. And from the switch I can ping 8.8.8.8 for example. But from the other network, I can't ping any hardware on the main office network.

How do I route from the 10.10.10.0/24 IP address range on the default VLAN to the 10.0.0.0/24 IP address range on the second VLAN as I can ping 10.0.0.73 from the other network but nothing else.

Comment: It's hard to picture exactly what you're doing.  Please edit your question to include a simple diagram.  Do you have a route from the Cisco router to your "other" network?

Comment: It would help if you share the actual configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> From the other network, I can ping the Procurve switch on both IP address ranges. And from the switch I can ping 8.8.8.8 for example. But from the other network, I can't ping any hardware on the main office network.

Routing requires both directions to work. If you've simply invented a new subnet behind the 2848 and route out of if with one of the subnet IP addresses, does the upstream network know where to route back any replies?

If not, you need to tell the upstream router/network that your new subnet is located behind the 2848. Either have static routes set up or configure a matching routing protocol like RIP or OSPF - which the aged 2848 doesn't speak.

If you can't get support for routing your subnet back that leaves only source NAT, "hiding" the subnet behind an (additional) NAT router.

In any case, you should check your company's policies if you're allowed any of above.